# generalize a function based on variable arguments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, args

This is my first post, and I am a beginner programmer. I hope you can help me become a better one.

I am trying to model a round robin domino game for five (05) players. On each round, only four (04) players play, in teams of two (02). The formula below does the trick, for a fixed number of 5 players.

My specific question is how to make it generic to any number of players; and how to make this one more efficient. (I assume it is possible, as I am a novice).

Thanks.

[Results to be modeled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Nsn.png)

Code:

```
import numpy

def calculo(*args):

    wints= numpy.zeros(len(args),dtype=int)

    for i, item in enumerate(args):

        if i is 0:
            if item[0]>item[1]:
                wints+=[1,1,0,0,0] # players 12
            else:
                wints+=[0,0,1,1,0] # players 34

        if i is 1:
            if item[0]>item[1]:
                wints+=[1,0,0,0,1] # players 15
            else:
                wints+=[0,1,1,0,0] # players 23

        if i is 2:
            if item[0]>item[1]:
                wints+=[1,0,0,1,0] # players 14
            else:
                wints+=[0,1,0,0,1] # players 25

        if i is 3:
            if item[0]>item[1]:
                wints+=[1,0,1,0,0] # players 13
            else:
                wints+=[0,0,0,1,1] # players 45

        if i is 4:
            if item[0]>item[1]:
                wints+=[0,1,0,1,0] # players 24
            else:
                wints+=[0,0,1,0,1] # players 35

    return wints

print(calculo([118,28],[128,66],[26,133],[111,0],[57,109]))
```

Comment: There's no reason to do `*args`. Just put everything inside a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but you can first reduce redundant code like this:

```
def calculo(items):
    wints = numpy.zeros(len(items), dtype=int)

    if items[0][0] > items[0][1]:
        wints += [1,1,0,0,0] # players 12
    else:
        wints += [0,0,1,1,0] # players 34

    if items[1][0] > items[1][1]:
        wints += [1,0,0,0,1] # players 15
    else:
        wints += [0,1,1,0,0] # players 23

    if items[2][0] > items[2][1]:
        wints += [1,0,0,1,0] # players 14
    else:
        wints += [0,1,0,0,1] # players 25

    if items[3][0] > items[3][1]:
        wints += [1,0,1,0,0] # players 13
    else:
        wints += [0,0,0,1,1] # players 45

    if items[4][0] > items[4][1]:
        wints += [0,1,0,1,0] # players 24
    else:
        wints += [0,0,1,0,1] # players 35

    return wints
```

---

There seems to be a pattern here...

```
def one_hot_encode(players, n):
    arr = numpy.zeros(n + 1, dtype=int)
    arr[players] = 1
    return arr[1:]

def calculo(scores, pairings, n_players):
    wints = numpy.zeros(n_players, dtype=int)

    for (s1, s2), (p1, p2) in zip(scores, pairings):
        winner = p1 if s1 > s2 else p2
        wints += one_hot_encode(winner, n_players)

    return wints

scores = [[118, 28], [128, 66], [26, 133], [111, 0], [57, 109]]
pairings = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,5],[2,3]], [[1,4],[2,5]], [[1,3],[4,5]], [[2,4],[3,5]] ]
print(calculo(scores, pairings, 5))
```

Outputs:

> [3 2 2 0 3]

You can generate the pairings as you desire.

Comment: Thank you Mateen. Let me try to explain further here. The list that the function takes is of len 5. Therefore, I have to validate the 5 cases with if-else. I would like to generate the validation automatically, based on the len of the arguments.

Comment: Mateen, thanks a lot and my kudos to you for this solution. This will definitely open my brain to new ways of coding. It solves the case for the 5 players, and any resulting score. However, when I try to model the 4 players, and vary the resulting scores, I get an error like the one below. Any Ideas around this? 

scores = [[118, 28], [128, 66], [25, 26]]
pairings = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,3],[2,4]], [[1,4],[2,3]] ] 

    arr[players] = 1
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4 @MateenUlhaq

Comment: @JesusLoaiza Good point. I've adjusted it to take in an additional parameter, `n_players`. With your new example, `calculo(scores, pairings, 4)` gives `[2 2 2 0]`.

Comment: Excellent @MateenUlhaq, it works like a charm!! Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have been trying the last couples of days "unsuccessfully" to generate the same output but with the cumulative scores. Would you be so kind as to give me a hint on how to proceed?